# Where is ssh dynamic tunnel traffic log?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, logs, ssh-tunneling

If a client established a ssh dynamic tunnel to a Ubuntu server, is there a log file on the server that records all the detailed traffics (client’s browser, etc.) on that tunnel? If there is, where is it? I checked `/var/log/secure`, there are ssh connection logged, but no detailed traffic.

Comment: An SSH tunnel doesn’t log the traffic that goes across it.  What you’d be looking for is something like Squid which can do that when properly configured.